# Can't get Firefox to stop caching

Tags: http, firefox, cache-control, http-caching

There are lots of question and answers about preventing the browser from caching and I've tried lots of them. It seems like `Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store` along with `Pragma: no-cache` and `Expires: 0` is supposed to do the trick. But, Firefox only makes a single request for my image.

Here are the response headers I'm sending. Is there anything obvious that's missing here?

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Cache-Control   no-cache,no-store,private,must-revalidate,max-stale=0,post-check=0,pre-check=0
Content-Length  4830
Content-Type    image/jpeg
Date    Thu, 23 Mar 2000 22:16:32 GMT
Etag    "706331614"
Expires 0
Last-Modified   Thu, 23 Mar 2000 22:16:31 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
Server  lighttpd/1.4.32
```

Comment: For another similar post on this same topic, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233115/to-avoid-cache-control-in-firefox