# To avoid cache control in firefox

Tags: firefox, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

When the response header is

> Cache-Control : no-store

Firefox stores in memory cache device.

If the response header is

> Cache-Control : no-cache

then firefox stores in disk cache device.

If the response header is

> Cache-Control : no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0

then firefox stores in memory cache device

However firefox caching the request in any of one cache device. How to avoid that

Comment: Looks like it may not be possible to prevent the _caching_, per the Mozilla [HTTP Caching FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching_FAQ).  However, the FAQ does suggest that the above `Cache-Control` header _should_ cause Firefox to _revalidate_ the cached responses each time, rather than serving/displaying stale data to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

1. try to set expire or max-age to minimum?
2. another example: Cache-Control: "private, no-cache, no-cache=Set-Cookie, proxy-revalidate"
3. also another way is to do like file.png?97887987979797 (not best...)
4. another example from google: 
   Cache-Control:  "private, max-age=0"
   Expires: "-1"